# converting each element in a group/list of number into other base

Tags: programming-languages

I am new to python programming. I am now trying to build a program which convert every element in a list of numbers of base 10 into its base 4. For example here, say i have numbers from 0 to 20 or more, I want to convert every number starting from 0 to numbers of base 4. The result should be like this

```
[[0,0],[0,1],...[1,1,0]
```

for numbers starting from 0 to 20. Here is what I wrote so far

```
for n in range(21):
       def base(n,b):
          result = []
          while n > 0:
                 result.insert(0, n % b)
                 n = n // b
          return result



print(base(n, 4))
```

For the result I got only for number 20 which is

```
[1,1,0]
```

Did I missed something here or there is another option to make it work?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I suggest you to take a basic course of programming.